In PostgreSQL how to get the hourly minimum of a value using a window function?
Let's assume we have the following data with one temperature measurement per second. The span of data is several years so there is a considerable number of rows. It is measurement data from a field device. The table has other columns as well but they are not relevant to the question.



Time
Temperature_deg_in_C




2024-11-01 00:00:00+00
20.1


2024-11-01 00:00:01+00
21.2


2024-11-01 00:00:02+00
21.6


2024-11-01 00:00:03+00
20.2


...
...


2026-12-31 23:59:57+00
25.4


2026-12-31 23:59:58+00
25.2


2026-12-31 23:59:59+00
25.6



I know that I can use a GROUP BY clause to get the averages over one hour windows between a specific start and end times like so:
  SELECT to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), AVG("Temperature_deg_in_C")
    FROM "measurements"
   WHERE "time" BETWEEN '2024-11-01' AND '2024-12-01'
GROUP BY to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH')

However, this syntax feels like a hack, and it doesn't quite bend to e.g. 10 second or other more complex window frames (or partitions).
Furthermore, I would like to know, specifically, how this is done correctly and performantly using the OVER, WINDOW, PARTITION BY, RANGE, ROWS and similar tools outlined in PostgreSQL manual.
UPDATE: Window functions cannot be used to achieve this goal on Postgres, as they do not create "buckets" or "frames" in the way I thought they did. GROUP BY is the way to achieve this.
The end goal is to find a solution where the window length and unit of measurement (minutes, hours, days), and the start and end time of the observing period are flexible but the query body itself stays the same. A parameterized query that is simple to understand, that is.

Perhaps the TimescaleDB extension will be helpful -- it has time buckets

window function are slow and for your purpose wrong, the group by will be sufficient fast and perfect for that purpose

In this query:
SELECT to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), AVG("Temperature_deg_in_C")
FROM "measurements"
WHERE "time" BETWEEN '2024-11-01' AND '2024-12-01'
GROUP BY 1

...you're converting the timestamp into bin identifiers which will be identical for each row in the group so they end up in the same bin. By changing the way this is computed, you can use time bins that aren't limited to 1 minute, 1 hour or 1 day.
For example, instead of to_char() you could use:
FLOOR( EXTRACT( epoch FROM "time" ) / bin_length )

This converts the postgres timestamps to UNIX timestamps (expressed in seconds) then divides by the bin_length (also in seconds). Then the floor results in an integer which is the bin identifier for this row. With this expression, bins will begin at UNIX timestamp zero and repeat at multiples of bin_length.
You could also use something like:
FLOOR( EXTRACT( epoch FROM ( "time" - start_time ) / bin_length )

This substracts "time" from the query parameter start_time, so the first bin will begin at "start_time" and bins will repeat at multiples of bin_length.
The result of the GROUP BY, will contain bin numbers. Then you can do the same operation in reverse to convert back to timestamps. For example:
SELECT start_time + '1 second'::INTERVAL * bin_id, m_avg FROM (
SELECT 
FLOOR( EXTRACT( epoch FROM ( "time" - start_time ) / bin_length ) AS bin_id,
avg( measurement ) m_avg,
...
GROUP BY bin_id
)

Or you could use the timestamp at the left edge of the bin as bin key, by replacing to_char() with something like that:
start_time + '1 second'::INTERVAL * FLOOR( 
    EXTRACT( epoch FROM ( "time" - start_time ) / bin_length ))


I've decided to accept this answer since after educating myself on how window functions work I've come to realize that they are not the proper tool for this job. Window functions (at least in Postgres) do not create "buckets" or "groups" like GROUP BY does.

Oops, I seem to have forgotten the question while writing the answer ;) yes window functions do not group rows, their purpose is to make calculations based on several related rows but the output contains as many rows as the input. For example difference between subsequent rows, running total, ranking, etc.

PLPgSQL query using windows function:
SELECT 
    to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), 

    ROUND(
        AVG(temperature_deg_in_c) OVER (
           PARTITION BY to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH')
        ), 
    2) AS AVG_TEMP

FROM measurements

WHERE time BETWEEN '2024-11-01' AND '2024-12-01';

alternative way with windows function:
SELECT to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH')
    ROUND(
        SUM(temperature_deg_in_c) OVER (PARTITION BY to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'))/
        FLOOR(COUNT(temperature_deg_in_c) OVER (PARTITION BY to_char("time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH')))
    ) AS COUNT_TEMP
    
FROM measurements
WHERE time BETWEEN '2024-11-01' AND '2024-12-01';

db<>fiddle

Downvote is not mine, sadly people downvote without comments.  You can improve your answer by explaining what you are doing.
